# Persist one record at a time compared to the whole list at once

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics

I have to choose between 2 approaches.

Persist my list in the data base using `MyList.Foreach(p => DoIt(p));`

-or-

Use something like `DoIt(MyList);`

`DoIt` is a DAL method in my separate layer.

What are the use cases for them?

I am interested in resource usage and performance between these two scenarios. My Dal uses `using` to create the connection object everytime the method is called.

Comment: "Less connections being created = better" seems to be a general rule of thumb.

Comment: Sure, but .NET has connection pooling internally and i was thinking that maybe is a better approach to go one for one using linq against the whole list...

Comment: If you compare creating one single connection to creating MyList.Count number of connections, in absolute numbers, connection pooling is irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah that's a stupid answer on my part. Let me get back to you on that :-P

Comment: Thanks, you could write it as an answer to flag it if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your connection is kept in the connection pool, you would do well to create and use the connection in a one-off (and in a `using` block) because looping and re-calling the connection for each element of the collection would undoubtedly cost more.

Although I'm not aware of the inner workings at this time, the internal checks on the pool necessary to see if the connection is still the same being called, would be skipped if you process the `List` as a whole.